# Alarm port state changed

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
if lsof -i :4444 | grep ESTABLISHED ;
then 
    paplay Alarm_Buzzer.ogg
fi
done
```

I'm trying to create a script that continously checks the state of a port. If the state changes, the script should play a sound (once) and continue checking for a change.

Port has two states; `LISTEN` & `ESTABLISHED`

Comment: Your question needs more clarity.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the clarification;

1. Start script
2. Get current port state
3. Continuously check for change, play sound if so

   - Override `last` if state changed

```
#!/bin/bash

# Port state at begin of script
# The awk part parses the string to only the last column containing;
# (LISTEN) OR (ESTABLISHED)
last=$(lsof -i :4444 | awk '{print $NF}')

# Continuously
while true; do

    # Get fresh port state
    state=$(lsof -i :4444 | awk '{print $NF}')

    # If it changed
    if [ "$state" != "$last" ]; then

        # Play sound
        paplay Alarm_Buzzer.ogg

        # Remember the new state
        last="$state"
    fi

    # No need to check so fast, sleep for a while (Thx @tomgalpin)
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This will have a ridiculous impact on CPU performance.

Comment: Even tho this was not asked by the OP, your completely right, I guess a `sleep 1` should be enough to not 'spam' the CPU.

Comment: break causing exit script I dont want to quit script just waiting always when port established it plays the alarm one time

Comment: So the scrip should never 'stop'? Keep checking if the port is active, but play the sound just once?

Comment: Nope,reach `break`  exit script

Comment: Please clarify the real question. The above script keeps checking until a port is available. Once it's found, the sound will play once, and the script will exit.

Comment: play once and waiting for others time no want to exit

Comment: @jali316 I'm sorry, but it's just getting more confusing. It's better to edit your post and explain the question clearly. The current state of the question is apparently not what you expect.